# Business Logic using Linq-To-SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, business-logic

I'm trying to implement business logic with my Linq-to-SQL class. A table in the class has al field: "IsActive" and a field: "InActiveDate".

I'm trying to fill the inactive date when the "IsActive" field (boolean) is changing.

For that I created al new class containing a public partial class for the entity that should change.

```
    partial void OnIsActiveChanged()
    {
        if ((bool)this.IsActive)
        {
            this.InActiveDate= null;
        }
        else
        {
            this.InActiveDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  The InActiveDate field stays empty in the database without a single error.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you're committing your changes to the database at all. Once you set the value on the object, you need to call `SubmitChanges();` on your DataContext.

Comment: I'm using a LinqDataSource with a detailsview. If I'm right the onchange event occurs after the changes are submitted in the detailsview. When stepping through the program it looks like changes are overwritten by the value supplied by the detailsview. IF thats correct, whats the use of the business-logic?

Answer (score 0):

Joel is right on target...LINQ draws data from the database and then treats it as a normal class. You can modify it all you like without altering the database. In order to actually save your work you need to set up your declare a variable for your DataContext

like below

```
SomeNameDataContext db = new SomeNameDataContext();

db.SubmitChanges();
```